# Invoking Rest Service from Java standalone application

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I'm creating an application that need to invoke a webservice to store some data.

This is needed because the application must be installed on different machines and after collecting data must save that on a central repository (my Rest WebService).

Looking on the net i've found many reference about:

- RestTemplate
- Spring Integration
- Apache Camel
- etc..

I'm pretty confused about all this technologies and i havent found a clean way to invoke a WebService.

Another point to take in consideration is that my "standalone" application will collect different kind of data and the protocol i will use to communicate with WebService should be simple, so i need (on WebService) a way to "understand" what data is getting and then transform it to save (on a Database, File etc).

If the question is off-topic or not relevant i could close this question.

Sorry but looking on the net i havent found only confusing post about Spring Integration, Apache Camel etc..

Comment: Are you familiar how to execute HTTP calls from Java? If yes, you have probably used Apache's HTTP client, or any other HTTP Client. To call REST service you simply do an HTTP call (GET or POST). There are so called "REST Clients", but you simply need to do an HTTP GET or POST. All the technologies you've mentioned are abstraction layers over "how to craft HTTP request". So I recommend you to read basic documentation on invoking REST services.

Comment: Yes, i know how to invoke webservice and how to make GET,POST, PUT etc... maybe the title and the description of my question is incorret... i would like to know how to structure this call and if these technologies can be used to write better code. Unfortunally on the web i havent find good resource where talk about this in a clean way, just "confused" blog post or few more..

Comment: Spring RestTemplate - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Jersey Client - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

Answer (score -1):

check Jersey , read section 5 thoroughly and you will have a working code in minutes [Jersey client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4260)

**Update:**
here is an example of how to do an HTTP GET towards an API using Jersey 2.0:

```
// you can register filters and other type of objects to the client config
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig());

WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/rest").path("resource");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

// here you use the class that maps the your api data usually marshalling is done from JSON
// but still you can marshall from different formats
YourDataObject reponse = response.readEntity(YourDataObject.class);
```

Comment: Try not to leave link-only answers. What happens if they change the URL? This answer becomes useless.

Comment: thanks guys for the feedback excuse my noobiness  :)